# Error: At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

I am trying to implement Random Forest on a dataset using the caret package in  R. Looking at the previous examples on this site I changed the column names and the factor levels. Nothing seems to working. Been getting the same error over and over again. Here is my code, structure of my dataset and the error:

```
model_rf = train(Promoted ~ Department + Region+ Education+Gender+ RecruitmentChannel+TrainingNumber+Age+LengthOfService +EmployeePerformance+AvgTrainingPerformance, data=train, method='rf', tuneLength=5, trControl = fitControl)
model_rf
predicteds_rf <- predict(model_rf, newdata=test)
```

> Error: At least one of the class levels is not a valid
>   R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are
>   generated because the variables names will be converted to 
>   Not.Promoted, Promoted . Please use factor levels that can be used as
>   valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).

```
> str(trainData)
'data.frame':   54808 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ EmployeeID            : int  65438 65141 7513 2542 48945 58896 20379 16290 73202 28911 ...
 $ Department            : Factor w/ 9 levels "Analytics","Finance",..: 8 5 8 8 9 1 5 5 1 8 ...
 $ Region                : Factor w/ 34 levels "region_1","region_10",..: 32 15 11 16 19 12 13 28 13 1 ...
 $ Education             : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Bachelor's",..: 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 4 ...
 $ Gender                : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","m": 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ RecruitmentChannel    : Factor w/ 3 levels "other","referred",..: 3 1 3 1 1 3 1 3 1 3 ...
 $ TrainingNumber        : Factor w/ 5 levels "Average training",..: 5 5 5 3 5 3 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Age                   : Factor w/ 3 levels "Middle Age","Old",..: 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 ...
 $ LengthOfService       : Factor w/ 6 levels "Junior","Mid Level",..: 6 2 6 6 1 6 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ EmployeePerformance   : Factor w/ 7 levels "Average Performer",..: 4 3 5 7 5 5 5 5 3 4 ...
 $ AvgTrainingPerformance: Factor w/ 6 levels "Average","Below Average",..: 5 1 2 2 4 6 2 1 6 2 ...
 $ Promoted              : Factor w/ 2 levels "Not Promoted",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Would be a big help if someone could provide me with some suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Some of the levels have names containing spaces (like "Middle Age"). This causes the error.

Comment: Levels shouldn't have spaces is it?

Comment: No. If you check out the function make.names, the name "a and b" for example is invalid, and the function corrects it to "a.and.b"

Comment: can you add a small sample of data with `dput(head(YourdataSet,5))`

Comment: Can you add `fitControl` to the question? I suspect some of your factors have low cardinality (unique values).

Answer (score 0):

Valid names for factor levels should **not**

1. contain spaces
2. start with a number
3. be an empty string

As you can see, your dataframe contains all three.

These requirements exist because whenever caret::train() runs a tree-based model (here random forests), it converts the factor levels into variables which are used to split the tree. Hence factor level labels become variable names.

So for each of these variables, you can convert the level names to valid labels with the following code.

```
trainData %>% 
  mutate(Education = factor(Education, 
          labels = make.names(levels(Education))))
```

Instead of `labels =` you can do `levels =` - the latter changes the data whereas the former changes the display (e.g. by print(dataframe)).